# How to protect a controller to only be visible from local network

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, asp.net-mvc-5, iis-8

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC 5 site that will have some kind of subsite that requires to only be visible/reachable from computers that are inside the local network.

Basically every other controller different than this specific one will be visible for everybody (internet) but the one I want to protect should only be visible by individuals accessing the site from company's network.

I know I can create a site in IIS and create an application folder inside it to protect it using IIS configuration, but AFAIK that will require to build another ASP.NET MVC project that will be served by that application folder, so It will require to maintain two sites.

Is this possible to be configured by code/web.config or the only way is to create two MVC sites?

I will appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

The thing is that MVC doesn't map to "folders" (in IIS). So if you *can't* do the right thing as you mentioned (separate app), then you're likely stuck with restricting at the `Controller`(s) level.

If:

- server is "local" to your network (LAN), not in some hosted environment, using some private IP address space, then you can do things like Filter by "local IP" - 10.x.x.x, 192.168.x.x - see [**private** network](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network)
- server is hosted externally, you'll have to find out *all* the ***public*** IP addresses you define as "local" (representing all the clients in your network), which could technically be 1 ***public*** ip address (for your entire local network) and do same.

I'm sure there are other ways depending on your environment's networking setup.